# BackgroundDownloader with oAuth

Tags: c#, oauth, uwp

I'm trying to download large file from server with oAuth.
If use backgrounddownloader it will fall with forbidden(403).
Is it real to authptificate via backgrounddownloader or maybe exists another downloader with progress.

Comment: Could you please revise your question to make it clear what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to perform a request with authentication using the BackgroundDownloader, you can add your Auth header using the SetRequestHeader on your BackgroundDownloader instance like this:

```
downloader.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "your-auth-header");
```